# Trying to dynamically filled columns based on list values and len

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have been trying to optimize as much as possible a data manipulation that takes two parts. I am working a pandas column where each value is a list with different length or NaN values and I want to extract the values to put them on column based on their position in the list.

Here is a reproductible example and what I have coded so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Charles', 'Charles2', 'Charles3'],
               'last_name': ['George', 'George2', 'George3'],
               'banking_number': [['NaN'], ['UK421'], ['UK123', 'FR789']]}
             )
```

```
len_banking_number = max(
    df.loc[
        df[
            'banking_number'
        ].notna()
    ]['banking_number'].str.len()
)
len_list = list(
    range(
        1, len_banking_number + 1
    )
)

for i in len_list:
  df[f'bank_{i}'] = np.nan
```

How would you get this result?

```
    df_final = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Charles', 'Charles2', 'Charles3'],
                   'last_name': ['George', 'George2', 'George3'],
                   'banking_number': [['NaN'], ['UK421'], ['UK123', 'FR789']],
                   'bank_1': ['NaN', 'UK', 'UK'],
                   'bank_2': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'FR']}
                 )
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Please explain the logic employed to produce the desired output given the input.  What logic is employed to determine you need columns for bank_1 and bank_2, how did you convert the banking _number input to the shown output for bank_1 and bank_2?

Comment: @itprorh66 yes sure! Goal would be: you have for example client Charles2 George2 which has one banking_number in a list. First and only element of this list is UK421, I would like to extract the two first strings 'UK' and put it in bank_1 (only one bank). For Charles3 George3 client, he has two banks that are stored in a list. First two strings of the first element would go to bank_1 and first two strings of the second element would go to bank_2. For the first client Charles George, since the list is filled with one NaN, I would like to put NaN in bank_1 and bank_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Charles', 'Charles2', 'Charles3'],
               'last_name': ['George', 'George2', 'George3'],
               'banking_number': [[None], ['UK421'], ['UK123', 'FR789']]}
             )

# split the banking_number column
df[['bank_1','bank_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['banking_number'].tolist(), index= df.index)

# keep only the first 2 characters (maybe not needed but I wanted to match your expected output)
def get_first_2_char(x):
    x=x[0:2] if x else x
    return x

for col in ['bank_1', 'bank_2']:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: get_first_2_char(x))
```

output:
[image: output]

**EDIT**

Following @itprorh86 remark, below is an updated version that can handle a different number of banks.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Charles', 'Charles2', 'Charles3'],
               'last_name': ['George', 'George2', 'George3'],
               'banking_number': [[None], ['UK421'], ['UK123', 'FR789']]}
             )

max_len = max(df['banking_number'].apply(lambda x: len(x)))
column_names = [f'bank_{i}' for i in range(1, max_len+1)]

# split the banking_number column
df[column_names] = pd.DataFrame(df['banking_number'].tolist(), index= df.index)

# keep only the first 2 characters
def get_first_2_char(x):
    x=x[0:2] if x else x
    return x

for col in column_names:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: get_first_2_char(x))
```

Comment: Would you say that your solution has a better scaling / performance profile than the second one ? It's hard for me to judge. In any case, thanks a lot for looking into this!!!

Comment: I don't think iterating on rows is a good thing, but to be honest I didn't take the time to compare both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach from the one suggested by @JulietteB.

```
def parseDF(df_in: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    key_cols = list(df_in.columns)
    max_banks = max(list(len(x) for x in df_in['banking_number'].to_list()))
    for nk in range(max_banks):
        key_cols.append(f'bank_{nk+1}')
    rslt = []
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        row = []
        row.append(df.iloc[r]['first_name'])
        row.append(df.iloc[r]['last_name'])
        b_number = df.iloc[r]['banking_number']
        print(b_number)
        row.append(b_number)
        for nw in range(max_banks):
            if nw < len(b_number):
                print(b_number[nw])
                row.append(b_number[nw])
            else:
                row.append('NaN')
        rslt.append(row)
        print(rslt)
    return pd.DataFrame(data= rslt, columns = key_cols)
```

This approach will provide the same answer but has the advantage of handling a different number of Banks

Given your input data, executing `parseDF(df)` will yield:

```
    first_name  last_name   banking_number  bank_1  bank_2
0   Charles George  [NaN]   NaN NaN
1   Charles2    George2 [UK421] UK421   NaN
2   Charles3    George3 [UK123, FR789]  UK123   FR789
```